# Storing data with different data types in a HashMap with single key

Tags: java, hashmap

I have the following structure of data with datatypes as below:

```
Name                   Type   
Keyval                 String        //This is the key element
x                      Float           
x2                     Float                
result                 Float
performance            String
```

I want to store this into an `HashMap` with Key as `keyval` and all others info (`x,x2,result,performance`) for the respective `keyval`.

**Output Example:**

```
[Keyval=com.a.service, x=0.05, x2=0.07, result=0.02, performance = IMPROVED]
[Keyval=com.b.service, x=0.03, x2=0.07, result=0.04, performance = IMPROVED]
[Keyval=com.c.service, x=0.15, x2=0.07, result=0.08, performance = DEGRADED]
```

How do I store it and how can I access it?

Comment: `Map<String, Value> map` where `Value` is the class that contains fields you quote to represent a value (x, x2, result and performance) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store all the element in a class (and a constructor) :

```
public class Element {
    float x;
    float x2;
    float result;
    String performance;

    public Element(float x, float x2, float result, String performance) {
        this.x = x;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.result = result;
        this.performance = performance;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Element{" + "x=" + x + ", x2=" + x2 + ", result=" + result + ", performance=" + performance + '}';
    }
}
```

To be used like this :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Element> map = new HashMap<String, Element>();
        map.put("com.a.service", new Element(0.05, 0.07, 0.02, "IMPROVED"));
        //...
        Element a = map.get("com.a.service"); //x=0.05, x2=0.07, result=0.02, performance = IMPROVED
}
```

To get back an element ;)

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your response. Actually, I have an issue retrieving the hashmap when I print the hashmap with "System.out.println(Arrays.asList(map4));" the list is printed as below:                                [{com.a.service=Element@12a3a380, com.b.service=Element@29453f44, com.c.service=Element@5cad8086, com.d.service=Element@6e0be858;                                                         Can you please help me om this ? @azro

Comment: It's because there is no "String toString() method in that class so it uses the Object one and print the reference you need to surcharge it (see my edit)

Comment: No prob, depends on your IDE you may have a place to generate these methods, like constructor, setter/getter, toString ... easily

Answer (score 1):

You can have map of type `Map<String, CustomObject> map`. Your `CustomObject` POJO looks like;

```
public class CustomObject {

 Float x;
 Float x2;
 Float result;
 String performance;

 // constructor , setter and getters
}
```

You can retrieve the value calling

```
CustomObject object = map.get('keyValue');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Value{
       String performance;
       float x, x2, result;

       public Value(float x, float x2, float result, String performance) {
        this.performance = performance;
        this.x = x;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.result = result;
       }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Value> map = new HashMap<>();

        // to add values
        map.put("com.a.service", new Value(0.03f, 0.07f, 0.04f, "IMPROVED"));

        // to access them
        Value value = map.get("com.a.service");

        System.out.printf("KeyValue= com.a.service , X= %.2f, X2= %.2f, Result= %.2f, Performance= %s",
                                         value.x, value.x2, value.result, value.performance ); 
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
KeyValue= com.a.service , X= 0.03, X2= 0.07, Result= 0.04, Performance= IMPROVED
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your response. Actually, I have an issue retrieving the hashmap when I print the hashmap with "System.out.println(Arrays.asList(map4));" the list is printed as below: [{com.a.service=Value@12a3a380, com.b.service=Value@29453f44, com.c.service=Value@5cad8086, com.d.service=Value@6e0be858; Can you please help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class `WrapperClass` which holds the below private field variables:

```
x                      Float           
x2                     Float                
result                 Float
performance            String
```

and a constructor :

```
public WrapperClass(Float x, Float x2, Float result, String performance) {
     this.x = x;
     this.x2 = x2;
     this.result = result;
     this.performance = performance; 
}
```

Then Define a `Map<KeyVal, WrapperClass> myMap = new HashMap<>();`

```
myMap.put("com.a.service", new WrapperClass(0.5,0.07,0.02,IMRPOVED));
myMap.put("com.b.service", new WrapperClass(0.03,0.07,0.04,IMRPOVED));
```

and so on ...

now you can get `myMap.get("com.a.service")` which will return `WrapperClass` object.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: This is not a "wrapper" class.